# Convert coordinates between two rotated systems

Tags: coordinates, openlayers-3, coordinate-transformation

I have a map with coordinates in meters and an overlaying building plan with pixel coordinates:

[image: Sample map with plan overlay]

I already know the scale factor and I am able to convert coordinates between the two systems if they are aligned (i.e. the overlay image is exactly horizontal with no rotation)--> conversionfactor (= number of overlay pixels in one meter on the map)

```
MAPx(ImageX) = centerpointX + ImageX * conversionfactor
MAPy(ImageY) = centerpointY + ImageY * conversionfactor
```

How can I convert between the coordinates if the overlay is rotated assuming that I have above formulas and I want to include a rotation angle?

EDIT (@tsauerwein):

Here is the marker style that you have requested:

```
  planStyle = function(feature, resolution){
        var style = new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.Icon({
                src: feature.dataURL,
                scale: feature.resolution / resolution,
                rotateWithView: true,
                rotation: feature.rotation * (Math.PI / 180),
                anchor: [.5, .5],
                anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
                anchorYUnits: 'fraction',
                opacity: feature.opacity
            })
        })
        return [style];
    };
```

Comment: @Craicerjack Why did you reject the edit? [tag:openlayers] should not be used with [tag:openlayers-3]. It says so in the description. [See this Meta Post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321540/5620297)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using `ol.source.ImageStatic`: When you configure your layer, you have the size of the image in pixels(e.g. width=500, height=200) and also the extent that this image covers in coordinates.

Now, if you have a coordinate, you can easily check if the coordinate is inside the image extent (`ol.extent.containsXY(extent, x, y)`). Then you can also translate the *real-world* coordinate to a pixel coordinate:

```
// image size
var width = 500;
var height = 250;

// image extent
var extent = [2000, 0, 4000, 1000];

// coordinates
var x = 3000;
var y = 500;

if (ol.extent.containsXY(extent, x, y)) {
  var pixelX = width * (x - extent[0]) / ol.extent.getWidth(extent);
  var pixelY = height * (y - extent[1]) / ol.extent.getHeight(extent);
}
```

Doing it like this, it doesn't matter if the map is rotated or not.

Comment: As far as I know, it is not possible to rotate a static image source, but I need to perform the rotation using ol and cannot save the rotated version beforehand and then import the resulting image

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I thought you were talking about a rotated map. You are right, it is not possible to rotate an image with an `ImageStatic` source. How are you currently displaying the building plan on the map?

Comment: I use ol.style.Icon which provides a rotation property

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code on how you configured the icon style? Especially how you are resizing the icon depending on the resolution.